# Rate limiting in postfix

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, rate-limiting, policyd

So i have been trying to make a mail servddder which is functioning fine now what i want now is i want to limit the amount of mail a mail user can send I have tried and failed with policyd I also posted a question for a topic but didnt got any response thought that If any of you guys have the solution to d so

So, basically what i want to achieve is I want to limit 2 email every 5 minutes per user hope That make it clear

So any suggestion about how can i do with That

link of my previous policyd question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `postfwd`.

A default smtpd on port 25 in my servers always has very tight restrictions: `mynetworks`=127.0.0.1, it doesn't permit any authentication and relaying and so on. It's just for receiving mail from other servers. So such mail server requires **anybody** to connect to submission port (587) and authenticate to be able to send mail outside.

This submission smtpd process at port 587 has a postfwd plugged in as a policy service in the `smtpd_sender_restrictions`. This is configured in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, like this:

```
...
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch,check_policy_service,inet:127.0.0.1:10040,permit
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
...
```

A policy service at localhost:10040 is the postfwd. Its startup is defined in Debian by `/etc/default/postfwd`, where it has the following (ones which are important for connection with Postfix):

```
CONF=/etc/postfix/postfwd.cf
INET=127.0.0.1
PORT=10040
```

This is used by systemd to build a commandline for postfwd executable (it's a Perl script actually). It sets further configuration file to `/etc/postfix/postfwd.cf`, where you define actual rules. Those rules can be arbitrary complex, but for your question it will be very simple, just a single line:

```
id=TWO_IN_FIVE; sender=~/.*/; action=rate(sender/2/300/REJECT only 2 messages per 5 minutes for $$sender)
```

`rate` is a rate-limiting feature of postfwd, and here it's set to permit 2 messages in 300 seconds, otherwise it'll reject with the specified message. `$$sender` is substitied with actual envelope sender of this mail. Please note, it counts each recipient as independend mail; if you try to send a mail with two recipients, it'll count as two mail; if you try to have three recipients, this service will block such message. You see, 2 messages in 5 minutes is very tight restriction.

For the compete description of the features of postfwd and syntax of this file please refer to the official [postfwd documentation](https://postfwd.org/doc.html).

Comment: Hello @NIikita Mam your given configuration has just worked for me with some minor changes...... I will be poting my changes and the solution and also have some question on the topic so do help 

THANKS......

Comment: Hello @nikita mam can you please tell me if we can limit in this way 

Limit ========================>
sender == someone@domain.com
id=TWO_IN_FIVE;  action=rate(sender/2/300/REJECT only 2 messages per 5 minutes for $$sender)
|
Thank you